# Not able to type in text input field in React.js after using React Hook

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I've just started out practising using React Hooks, and I'm trying to set the state in a basic form.

My code is below, I followed a couple of tutorials on the internet however I can't figure out why when I run the app, I am unable to type in the text field. Am I missing something obvious?

[image: Cannot enter text]

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';

function UserForm() {
    const [gender, setGender] = useState("");

    return (
                <input
                    value={gender}
                    onChange={e => setGender(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Gender"
                    type="text"
                    name="gender"
                />

    )
}

export default UserForm;
```

Comment: if you remove the `View` and `Content` wrappers - does it work?

Comment: No it doesn't, so I've removed them form the code example.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it - recreated it in a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-villani-pdzuh?file=/src/App.js. ... can you show us how you are using `UserForm`?

Comment: oh wow that's interesting. Good to know the actual code works, now let me have a dig around with the repo I'm using to find out why it's not letting me enter text